# constructor leads to "use of deleted function" error

Tags: c++, boost, struct, constructor, boost-asio

I'm trying to initialize a variable internal to my structure by calling a custom constructor

This is for a https project that uses boost asio to communicate with a server. Basically I want to initialize an IO context with an struct with parameters. The error happens specifically when I add the `... : stream(ioc,ctx)`

This is my struct

```
struct HTTPSQueryStruct
 {

   ssl::stream<tcp::socket> stream;

   HTTPSQueryStruct(boost::asio::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx) : stream(ioc,ctx)
   {
   }

 };
```

And this is how Im calling it

```
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::sslv23_client};
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer); /* Set to verify host's ssl */
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();        /* Load CA certificates */

    HTTPSQueryStruct query = HTTPSQueryStruct(ioc, ctx);
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
error: use of deleted function ‘HttpsCom::HTTPSQueryStruct::HTTPSQueryStruct(HttpsCom::HTTPSQueryStruct&&)’
     HTTPSQueryStruct query = HTTPSQueryStruct(ioc, ctx);
note: ‘HttpsCom::HTTPSQueryStruct::HTTPSQueryStruct(HttpsCom::HTTPSQueryStruct&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   struct HTTPSQueryStruct
error: use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::stream(const boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&)’
In file included from class/HttpsCom.h:10:0,
                 from class/HttpsCom.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp:64:7: note: ‘boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::stream(const boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that a `ssl::stream<tcp::socket>` can't be copied, and you have one as a member.
(That it can't be copied is what the enormous `use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::ssl::stream<...` line is trying to say, in far too may words.)

Initialise directly instead of by copying

```
HTTPSQueryStruct query(ioc, ctx);
```

You could also add a move constructor (you might want one later)

```
HTTPSQueryStruct(HTTPSQueryStruct&& other) 
   : stream(std::move(other.stream))
{
}
```

but copy-initialisation only adds noise, and I would stick with direct initialisation.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Would you mind explaining me why one way works and the other one does not?

Comment: this asio ssl stream is moveable but not copyable because boost::asio's socket is moveable but not copyable. Hence the reason you will need to `std::move()`.. To be honest I also don't like it.